# Iframe open link in specific target on page

Tags: html, iframe

I am coding simple html page with menu on the left side. when users click on the menu links I want the links will open on the right side.
In the past I used the iframe tag, but I want to know if there is a new way or another ways to do it?

```
<iframe name="rightSide" src="index.html" align="top" height="100%" width="100%">
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the link, set up a target="rightSide" attribute.  This will load the url in the link into the IFrame.

```
<a href="http://www.someplace.com/pagetoload.html" target="rightSide">Load Me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code below

```
<iframe name="myFrame"></iframe>
```

and on target

```
<a href="myFrame"></a>
```